SwiftUI Observable environment compiler issue - cannot find in scope
Suppose I have a simple @Observable like
@Observable class Navigation {
    var path = NavigationPath()
}

And make an environment in my app structure like the migrating to observable docs recommend
@main
struct ObservableTestApp: App {
    @State private var navigation = Navigation()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(navigation)
        }
    }
}

I find that trying to use the @Environment from my view with NavigationStack like
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(Navigation.self) private var navigation

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigation.path) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

Raises this compiler error

Cannot find '$navigation' in scope

If we defined the @State on the ContentView instead, there is no compiler error.
Additionally, if I revert this to pre iOS 17 @ObservableObject using @StateObject and @EnvironmentObject (etc) then the compiler is fine with it. So it seems to be an issue with the new @Observable. Or perhaps my usage of it.
I understand there is an easy workaround but @ObservableObject behaving differently to @Observable is worth questioning.

@Observable is for your models like a Book, navigation is view data so you should try to use a state for NavigationPath or put it in a state struct if you have other vars/logic related to navigation.

You shouldn't use @State with classes, it'll leak them beacuse the initial value is init every time. Currently you need to also conform the @Observable to @ObservableObject and use @StateObject to prevent the leak. But as I said this should only be for models or stores that load or save, not for simple view data.

Hey @malhal, in the docs I linked in the question, I built the @Observables in the same way Apple recommended. Using NavigationPath in its own state is fair enough though, I only chose it because it was a common example. Thanks for this information though.

Sorry I don't know why Apple did that example it is not right, maybe some intern did it I guess.

You need to use Bindable to get a bindable version of navigation.
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(Navigation.self) private var navigation

    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var navigation = navigation
        NavigationStack(path: $navigation.path) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

See the documentation, including this example:
struct TitleEditView: View {
    @Environment(Book.self) private var book


    var body: some View {
        @Bindable var book = book
        TextField("Title", text: $book.title)
    }
}


Thanks, you're right, the documentation is pretty clear on that. Not sure how much I like having @Bindable var navigation = navigation in the body but that is indeed what it says. Thanks again

It needs to be in the body because you need the binding to be created each time the view is refreshed.
